# iOS: Is it allowed to cache Game Center usernames?

Tags: ios, game-center

Is it allowed to cache Game Center usernames in my own web database (just the usernames, no other data) or is it against Apple's policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 6.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines - harvesting Game Center information can lead to you being removed from the developer program (and all of your apps being removed from sale, I assume). So, a pretty strict 'no' from Apple.